# Dropdown list not showing the saved value after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, kendo-ui

I have a dropdownlist for Page location with 2 values. When I select a value from the list and click on Save, the value is saved in the database. But when I reload the page, the value which is first in the selection criteria is shown and when I edit other values and click on Save, the value for Page location is also changed. The issue is, I want to see the value which I changed for the Page location when the page is refreshed. Below is my code. Function 'edit' is called when I click on edit of the Page location.

HTML Code:

```
<script id="editTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div class = "row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <label  style="display:none;">Id:</label>
  <input type="hidden" id='ID' class="k-textbox" value="#=node.id #" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
  <label >PageLocation:</label>
  <select id = "pl">
  <option value="local">local</option>
  <option value="New Window" >New Window</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <button id="save" class="k-button k-primary">Save</button>
  </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function edit(itemid){
var editTemplate = kendo.template($("#editTemplate").html());
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
var selectedNode = treeview.select();
var node = treeview.dataItem(selectedNode);

$("<div/>")
    .html(editTemplate({ node: node}))
    .appendTo("body")
    .kendoWindow({
        modal: true,
        deactivate: function () {
            this.destroy();
        }
    })
 .on("click", ".k-primary", function (e) {     
    var dialog = $(e.currentTarget).closest("[data-role=window]").getKendoWindow();
    var textbox = dialog.element.find(".k-textbox");
    var Id = $('#ID').val();
    var PageLocation = $('#pl').val();
    node.text = undefined;
    node.set("Pagelocation", PageLocation);
    node.set("id", Id);
    dialog.close();
    var treenode = treeview.dataSource.get(itemid);
    treenode.set("Pagelocation", PageLocation);
    treenode.set("id", Id);
       treenode.PAGE_LOCATION = PageLocation;
    treenode.ID = Id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/TreeServices.asmx/UpdateTree",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        //data: JSON.stringify({ "erpLinksJson": treenode, NodeId: nid, RoleId: rid })
        data: JSON.stringify({ "LinksJson": treenode})
    });



    console.log(JSON.stringify(treenode));
 })


}
```

Service:

```
        [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public String UpdateTree(LinksJSON LinksJson)
    {
        using (var context = new Data.WebEntities())
        {

            context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var updNode = context.Links.Where(c => c.ID == LinksJson.ID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (updNode != null)
            {
                updNode.ID = erpLinksJson.ID;
                updNode.PAGE_LOCATION = erpLinksJson.PAGE_LOCATION;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return JSON.Serialize(updNode);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the dropdown to show what's in the database?

Comment: I have a service which i called her 'updateTree' . let me post the code for that.

Comment: In your jQuery or ASP.NET code, where do you set the selected dropdown value on page refresh?

Comment: I will refresh the page manually. So do we need to write anything on page refresh or page reload on aspx.cs . If so can you help me that.

Comment: There is no code which links the PAGE_LOCATION value in your service method with the treeview, that we can see. Nor is there a connection between the `<select id = "pl">` element and that PageLocation value. Note that you have `value="#=node.id #"` for your ID field. Perhaps you need something similar for your PageLocation select?

Comment: I tried this but didnt work {select id = "pl" # if (node.PageLoacation) { # selected="selected" # } #>
    <option value="local">local</option>
    <option value="New Window" >New Window</option>
    </select>}